# Spring Boot Tomcat 8 session replication

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, high-availability, session-replication

I need to move my application into HA mode. I use Spring Boot, Tomcat 8. Right now I use plain session mechanism.

In order to move my application into HA cluster I need to implement Session replication.

Is it enough to implement approach described in this document [Redis Spring Session - Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot.html) or do I also need to configure Tomcat cluster ?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623311/how-to-setup-a-spring-boot-application-with-embedded-tomcat-session-clustering