# Spring Security Custom Login Site with 3rd Party Session Cookie

Tags: session, cookies, spring-security, spring-boot, openam

I am creating a Spring Boot web application that will act as the login site for my users.  Behind the scenes through a REST API, it's using OpenAM to validate the credentials and create a session token.  I expect that token will be used to to manage session for this login site and all the other sites we offer our users (single-sign on).

I would like the SpringBoot application to be stateless.  This makes deployments much easier.  While the site should be stateless, clearly we are still keeping session state in OpenAM.

I'm struggling with how to configure Spring Security to allow the cookie to represent a valid session that Spring Security recognizes.  When I make the application stateless, it causes all sorts of the problems with the CSRF protections because it thinks we're re-authenticating with every request that has a OpenAM session token in a cookie and creates a new CSRF headers (to protected against session fixation).

I'm using PreAuthenticationToken for my Authentication type.  Should I be using RembemberMeAuthenticationToken?  Do I need to introduce a new SessionAuthenticationStrategy?  Ideally, only the actual login POST makes Spring Security think a new session was created.  For all subsequent requests that have the session cookie, it should just let it through like it's authenticated. (I will be validating the token with OpenAM with every request)

Thoughts?
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I created a hybrid site that utilizes both the ForgeRock session token and the default Spring Security HttpSession.  To provide CSRF and session hijack protection, it's very challenging to create a totally session-less application.

So, my app utilizes the Spring session to provide CSRF and session hijack projection and to also act as a cache.  The Spring session lasts for 30 seconds, during which time, all requests utilized the stored principal information and don't need to query ForgeRock to validate it.  After 30 seconds, the Spring session expires and re-validates the ForgeRock session and acquires updated principal information from OpenAM.

I implemented a few hooks in the Spring Security app to enable this functionality.  I utilized Spring Boot, Spring Security, and the Java Configuration way of wiring it all together.

- I replaced the `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` filter with my own OpenAmCookieAuthentication filter.  In the doFilter() method it checks the duration of the HttpSession if it exists.  If longer than 'x' seconds, it invalidates the session.  This forces future filters to re-validate the OpenAM cookie and get the OpenAM principal info.
- I replaced the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` filter with my own filter.  To be clear, I didn't implement my own filter here, I just configured an `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` instance.  I set my own custom success and failure handlers

  - I created my own success handler that sets the OpenAM session cookie upon successful authentication with OpenAM.  It extended `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`
  - I created my own failure handler to handled failed logins which clears cookies.  It extended `ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler`
- Overrode the `authenticationManagerBean()`.  It still utilizes the ProviderManager class, but I pass in my own list of authentication providers

  - Create a `UserDetailsService` that implements the `AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>` interface.  It is used when there is an OpenAM session token that needs to be validated (after Spring session expires after 30 seconds)
  - Create authentication provider that implements the `AuthenticationProvider` interface.  This is utilized during the standard login processes to validate the user credentials with OpenAM.

Finally, since I couldn't make the app totally stateless, I implemented simple session replication using the embedded Tomcat instance.  This implementation was inspired by this post: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623311/how-to-setup-a-spring-boot-application-with-embedded-tomcat-session-clustering%20Embbeded%20Tomcat%20Session%20Clustering)